# SQL query, struggling to count instances/occurrences with COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to count the number of visits from this two tables below:

Pets table:

[image]

Visits table:

[image]

And here is my `SQL`:

```
 SELECT pet_name, pet_type
 FROM pets p
 JOIN visits v
 ON p.petid = v.petid
 SELECT COUNT(petid) AS "NUMBER OF VISITS" FROM visits
 WHERE petid = "PT5"
```

And it's returning this error message:

```
 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pet_name, p.pet_type, COUNT(v.petid) AS "NUMBER OF VISITS"
FROM pets p
JOIN visits v ON p.petid = v.petid
WHERE p.petid = "PT5"
GROUP BY p.pet_name, p.pet_type
```